# C fscanf to parse string with whitespace

Tags: c, scanf

I want to parse some string like this：

```
Chain FW_USER_IN (0 references)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.10.12
   0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.10.12
```

I needn't top two line!
My code is like this,but i can get destination field!

```
FILE *handle;
char *str1;
int num1;
handle = popen("iptables -t mangle -x -v -L FW_USER_IN -n","r");

while (('\n' != fgetc(handle)) && !feof(handle));
while (('\n' != fgetc(handle)) && !feof(handle));
num1 =1;
while(num1=1){
    num1 = fscanf(handle,"%*d %*d %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %s",str1);
    printf("str1:%s\n",str1);
}  
fclose(handle);
```

but I got the str1 always is NULL!
How can I do?

Comment: That's not how `fscanf` works - the value of `str1` will be the same before and after scanning, but the contents have changed. (You must provide space to hold the contents beforehand, though; see R Sahu's answer.)

Comment: "C fscanf to parse string with whitespace" - no, you should **not** use `fscanf()` for parsing strings.

Comment: thanks all！I am a rookie in c，thanks！

Comment: `while(num1=1){` --> `while(num1==1){`

Answer (score 2):

You have not allocated memory for `str1`. That's the core problem. `scanf` is reading into uninitialized memory, which leads to undefined behavior.

**Update**

As @BLUEPIXY pointed out in a comment, you also need to change

```
while(num1=1){
```

to

```
while(num1==1){
```

Comment: Thank you very much!This had spent me 3 days!